# iPhone: Publishing a story to a user's stream (using their user name)

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to publish something on a user's wall. The description should contain a reference to the user's name.

e.g.

"Max has just had scrambled eggs for breakfast."

Now I am able to post to a user's wall through

```
[facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
```

What I do not yet know how to do is include the (facebook)username in the description for the post.

Also, stream.publish is part of the Legacy REST API. What would the alternative look like in the Graph API? And can it be called exactly the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I seem to have figured out the first part, namely how to get information on the currently logged in user:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

But how do I know which request

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

is currently processing? I don't see any unique properties in these requests coming from facebook. Right now my approach is to create custom objects that implement FBRequestDelegate and set them as delegates depending on which request I am making (well, actually many instances of one object with each one knowing which type of request it belongs to).

Anyone have a better solution to this?